# WPF Binding Confusion: Composite DependencyObject

Tags: c#, user-controls, binding, dependencyobject

I have a DependencyObject class composition that looks like the following:

```
public class A : DependencyObject {
    public AB AB { get { ... } set { ... } }
    public AB AC { get { ... } set { ... } }
}

public class AB : DependencyObject {
    public string Property1 { get { ... } set { ... } }
    public string Property2 { get { ... } set { ... } }
    public string Property3 { get { ... } set { ... } }
}

public class AC : DependencyObject {
    public string Property1 { get { ... } set { ... } }
    public string Property2 { get { ... } set { ... } }
}
```

On A, AB and AC all properties perform the typical GetValue and SetValue operations referencing static properties per usual.

Now, classes A, AB and AC have corresponding UserControls AGroupBox, ABGrid, ACGrid. AGroupBox has a root A class property, ABGrid has a root AB class property and ACGrid has a root AC class property.

Both ABGrid and ACGrid have working bindings (e.g., ABGrid Contains a TextBox control whose Text property is twoway bound to AB's Property1.) I've verified this by creating a simple Window and having ABGrid be Window's only Content child and in the code behind setting ABGrid.AB = new AB(); same scenario for ACGrid.AC = new AC();.

The problem is when I try to do similarlly with with AGroupBox. I try adding AGroupBox as the single child of Window's Content in XAML, and set the AGroupBox.A property to new A() {AB = new AB(), AC = new AC()}; and the binding of the controls fails. AB and AC have default values for their PropertyN properties.

Any insights on what I'm missing? Is there a different route I should be taking?

EDIT: Additional Comment- If I add a string property to A, (String1) and bind it to the Text part of the GroupBox then the binding to that property works, but not to the AC and AB property of A.

EDIT-2: Per David Hay's request (all code is in namespace wpfStackOverflow):

**A.cs**

```
public class A : DependencyObject {
    static public DependencyProperty BProperty { get; private set; }
    static public DependencyProperty CProperty { get; private set; }
    static public DependencyProperty PropertyProperty { get; private set; }

    static A() {
        BProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("B", typeof(B), typeof(A));
        CProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("C", typeof(C), typeof(A));
        PropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Property", typeof(string), typeof(A));
    }

    public B B {
        get { return (B)GetValue(BProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BProperty, value); }
    }

    public C C {
        get { return (C)GetValue(CProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CProperty, value); }
    }

    public string Property {
        get { return (string)GetValue(PropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    public A() {
        Property = "A's Default Value";
        B = new B();
        C = new C();
    }
}
```

**B.cs**

```
public class B : DependencyObject {
    static public DependencyProperty PropertyProperty { get; private set; }

    static B() {
        PropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Property", typeof(string), typeof(B));
    }

    public string Property {
        get { return (string)GetValue(PropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    public B() {
        Property = "B's Default Value";
    }
}
```

**C.cs**

```
public class C : DependencyObject {
    static public DependencyProperty PropertyProperty { get; private set; }

    static C() {
        PropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Property", typeof(string), typeof(C));
    }

    public string Property {
        get { return (string)GetValue(PropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    public C() {
        Property = "C's Default Value";
    }
}
```

**AGroupBox.xaml**

```
<UserControl 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpfStackOverflow"
    x:Class="wpfStackOverflow.AGroupBox"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=A}"
    Width="300"
    Height="72"
    >
    <GroupBox Header="{Binding Property}">
        <StackPanel >
            <local:BGrid B="{Binding B}"/>
            <local:CGrid C="{Binding C}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>
</UserControl>
```

**AGroupBox.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class AGroupBox : UserControl {
    static public DependencyProperty AProperty { get; private set; }

    static AGroupBox() {
        AProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("A", typeof(A), typeof(AGroupBox));
    }

    public A A {
        get { return (A)GetValue(AProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AProperty, value); }
    }

    public AGroupBox() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**BGrid.xaml**

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="wpfStackOverflow.BGrid"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=B}"
    >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="Property"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Property}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**BGrid.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class BGrid : UserControl {
    static public DependencyProperty BProperty { get; private set; }

    static BGrid() {
        BProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("B", typeof(B), typeof(BGrid));
    }

    public B B {
        get { return (B)GetValue(BProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BProperty, value); }
    }

    public BGrid() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**CGrid.xaml**

```
<UserControl 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="wpfStackOverflow.CGrid"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=C}"
    >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="Property"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Property}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**CGrid.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class CGrid : UserControl {
    static public DependencyProperty CProperty { get; private set; }

    static CGrid() {
        CProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("C", typeof(C), typeof(CGrid));
    }

    public C C {
        get { return (C)GetValue(CProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CProperty, value); }
    }

    public CGrid() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**window1.xaml**

```
<Window 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpfStackOverflow"
    x:Class="wpfStackOverflow.Window1"
    Width="400"
    Height="200"
>
    <local:AGroupBox x:Name="aGroupBox" />
</Window>
```

**Window1.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class Window1 : Window {
    public Window1() {
        InitializeComponent();

        aGroupBox.A = new A()
        {
            Property = "A's Custom Property Value",
            B = new B()
            {
                Property = "B's Custom Property Value"
            },
            C = new C()
            {
                Property = "C's Custom Property Value"
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: We're going to have to see the XAML for the AGroupBox -- specifically the binding declaration -- in order to help here.  My guess is that your binding statements are not set up correctly to access the appropriate data.  Also, what is the readout of the binding failed message in debug output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try substituting the following into AGroupBox.xaml

```
<local:BGrid B="{Binding Path=A.B, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type local:AGroupBox}}}"/>
<local:CGrid C="{Binding Path=A.C, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type local:AGroupBox}}}"/>
```

It was not resolving the datacontext properly for those two lines, and so was not looking in the right place for B and C.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance! I looked in the debug output from the Output window in Visual Studio and didn't any binding warnings, how did you go about identifying the issue? Any thoughts on a less verbose solution?

Comment: Here is a link to a good article on some debugging techniques for binding:
http://beacosta.com/blog/?p=52

I know that there is a cleaner way to do it (similar to your initial attempt), but I can't conjure it up mentally right now.